# set different CSS style for active a href

Tags: css, href

How can I set different CSS style for the active link in menu bar? I have done this styling.

```
a.selected {
  color: red;
  background: #efefef;
}
<ul>
  <li><a href="villblock.aspx">villa</a></li>
  <li><a href="lateFine.aspx" class="selected">fine</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS effect is shown only in the `lateFine.aspx` but when I click on other link, CSS effect is not shown. How can I make this CSS effect i.e., change the CSS style for active link ?

Comment: This will be on your server side language - what is adding the `selected` class to your links?

Comment: _“but when I click on other link, CSS effect is not shown”_ - unclear what you mean. So you are on `villblock.aspx` now - did you change the HTML accordingly, so that _that_ link element now has the `selected` class?

Comment: do you mean hover instead of click? Because when you click on it, you will be navigated away.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery or javascript to add and remove class **onclick** event.

```js
$("#villa").click(function(){
$("#villa").addClass('selected');
$("#fine").removeClass('selected');
})

$("#fine").click(function(){
$("#fine").addClass('selected');
$("#villa").removeClass('selected');
})
```

```css
.selected {
  color: red;
  background: #efefef;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a  id="villa">villa</a></li>
  <li><a  id="fine">fine</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: but they will navigate to a new page so this won't work

Comment: yes, if he wants to navigate to new page then there is no need for adding or removing any class.

Comment: I think the question is how does he add the selected class to the link on the new page but OP needs to clarify

Comment: oh okay, @Pete.Will wait for his clarification first.